# ArcMap hangs on "Initializing Application..." when starting from Visual Studio?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, visual-studio

This has worked just fine for years; I don't know what changed.  ArcMap 10.0 starts just fine on its own, it's just when using the debugger to test my add-in that it won't start.  The add-in, once compiled and installed, runs just fine.

Possibly related is an issue where in Windows Explorer, if I delete a file, it will not disappear unless I hit 'refresh'. This started happening around the same time that ArcMap 10.0 wouldn't start from Visual Studio.

Comment: This kind of problem is often difficult to diagnose, there are so many things that are going on during that step. Can you create a simple form (non-Esri) and debug that (to see if it's Visual Studio). In ArcCatalog remove all connected folders that aren't viatal. Do you have an SDE/ODBC connection? If so, has that database become inaccessible?

Comment: Also, look at your %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.X\ArcToolbox\log, %TEMP% and %TMP% folders, Esri stores some information there on startup.. if your system drive is nearly full or badly fragmented it might have issues writing temp files. Perhaps rename your Normal.mxt and .gxt to see if they've gone a little bad...

Comment: Thanks:  I have no SDE/ODBC connections.  All folder connections are accessible.  I installed ArcGIS 10.3 (trial) as well as Visual Studio Professional 2013; I have the same problem with the new software 10.3.  Next, I'll try and create a simple non-ESRI form.

Comment: I made a simple Windows Forms application; that worked just fine.  I'm in the process of defragmenting my hard drive; hopefully that will do the trick.